# getLastSignedInAccount / LastSignedInAccount

Tags: xamarin.android, google-signin, google-oauth

The Google sign [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in#check_for_an_existing_signed-in_user) makes mention of checking for an existing user with the call:

```
GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
```

What is the equivalent when using Xamarin, where is it located?  Or does it not exist in which case how do I handle when my user has already signed in with Google.  The [Xamarin demo](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/google-services/SigninQuickstart) of the project doesn't contain the equivalent code.

Answer (score 0):

use capital G

```
GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.GetLastSignedInAccount(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have a Nuget reference to the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Auth package.
Also add a reference to :

```
using Android.Gms.Auth.Api.SignIn;
```